# Get "Developer Options -> Pointer location" logs in android

Tags: android

For the research I am doing, I am required to collect data from user interaction with android devices ICS or better for touch inputs. I was thinking the best way to do so would be to use the **Pointer Location** available under **Developer Options** settings. I traced the source code that recreated that into a program was able to see the logs from that program through logcat, but I am not able to see it when I am running from the settings. Could anyone please point me into a right direction on how can I go about getting those log files? Here's the source that seems to be responsible for logging which does fine in my application but not through the settings menu:

```
private void More ...logPointerCoords(MotionEvent.PointerCoords coords, int id) {
    Log.i(TAG, mText.clear()
            .append("Pointer ").append(id + 1)
            .append(": (").append(coords.x, 3).append(", ").append(coords.y, 3)
            .append(") Pressure=").append(coords.pressure, 3)
            .append(" Size=").append(coords.size, 3)
            .append(" TouchMajor=").append(coords.touchMajor, 3)
            .append(" TouchMinor=").append(coords.touchMinor, 3)
            .append(" ToolMajor=").append(coords.toolMajor, 3)
            .append(" ToolMinor=").append(coords.toolMinor, 3)
            .append(" Orientation=").append((float)(coords.orientation * 180 / Math.PI), 1)
            .append("deg").toString());
}
```

**Edit on what I did with source:**

I recreated a program/app from two class: **public class PointerLocationView extends View** called from **public class PointerLocation extends Activity** and managed to replicate the same functionality in an activity.

Thank your for the help.

Comment: I couldn't understand this part " I traced the source code that recreated that into a program was able to see the logs from that program through logcat," did you write a new app derived from the source of pointer location tracking?

Comment: Yes. I recreated a program from two class:  public class PointerLocationView extends View called from public class PointerLocation extends Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone in the future interested into something like this, repetitouch is great. I tried it for sometime but I needed something extra and different ui. Hence I wrote a program for myself with getevent and sendevent for rooted phone.

Comment: Hi. Can you give getevent and sendevent commands inside an android application not using adb? I need to record and replay touch events inside an android application. I think I should use them but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible to record the system wide touches programmatically: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13992/how-can-i-record-touches

And I couldn't generate any touch log with the pointer location developer option. It only logs when you turn it on once and they are not pointer locations they are like general information.

Maybe this application might give you an idea(I haven't tried it)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.free

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2270795